# Can't connect to a firebird server on docker

Tags: docker, firebird, isql

I'm a macOS user and I got weird errors just to create a database with firebird. I saw that there are some dock containers with firebird that run just fine ( i was able to create databases, perform queries and so on) but when I tried to connect from my local ISQL or razorSQL client ( through JDBC), I get some weird errors like  "unavailable database" or "can't open file"

I'm also not sure how **ISQL CONNECT** string really works because every site I saw there is a different one.

I got this docker image: ( https://hub.docker.com/r/jacobalberty/firebird/)

I created my container like this:

```
docker run -d --name firebird -p 3050:3050 -v /data/firebird/databases:/databases jacobalberty/firebird:2.5-ss
```

my docker-machine IP is:

```
192.168.99.100
```

I tried to connect like this:

```
CONNECT '0.0.0.0:3050://databases/test.fdb' user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey';
unavailable database
```

And also like this:

```
CONNECT '192.168.99.100:/databases/test.fdb' user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey';
connection rejected by remote interface


CONNECT '192.168.99.100:3050:/databases/test.fdb' user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey';
 Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 08001
 unavailable database
```

When i enter the docker container, the file is there:

```
root@e4212b9f9d16:/databases# pwd
/databases
root@e4212b9f9d16:/databases# ls
test.fdb
```

Also, I'm not sure how to check if the firebird server is running ( i guess it is cause I can 'connect' to a database inside the container'.. but the docker container is definally up and running - did a successful telnet on the ip and port)

I also tried to use the container IP (172.17.0.2) but i got a timeout

Im most familiar with mysql and SQLite never touched a firebird db before and as the user got this DB, i have to mock it, develop an app using fake data and then connect it to the real firebird (so changing the DB is not an option)

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using in that docker image, and which Firebird version of ISQL/libfbclient are you using on your own machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the standard documentation about 'create your firebird server' don't mention but you on firebird.conf, the variable **RemoteBindAddress** must be empty

File:

```
/etc/firebird/2.5/firebird.conf
```

Lines changed:

```
RemoteBindAddress =
#RemoteBindAddress = localhost
```

Thanks for all the

Answer (score 2):

Most of your problems are your connection string, it should be `<host>/<port>:<database-path-or-alias>`, where leaving of `/<port>` will default to port 3050.

This accounts for all your problems except for

> ```
> CONNECT '192.168.99.100:/databases/test.fdb' user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey';
> connection rejected by remote interface
> ```

As that connection string is a valid one.

This error means that you were able to connect to the server, but the connection was rejected. This might - for example - happen when you use Firebird 3, but connect using a Firebird 2.5 ISQL/fbclient library, and haven't relaxed the security settings of Firebird 3 (see [Legacy Authentication](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-compat-legacyauth.html) in the Firebird 3 release notes).

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out if the server is running, use:

```
docker ps
```

In order to figure out if the server actually started, or errored out upon start, start the container without the -d and look at the log messages when it runs:

```
docker run --name firebird -p 3050:3050 -v /data/firebird/databases:/databases jacobalberty/firebird:2.5-ss
```

Comment: The docker container is running (otherwise i could not enter the container and connect to the database inside it)

Comment: Can you telnet into the port the database is supposed to be exposed on?

Comment: Yeap, its connecting through telnet

Comment: Docker sets up other IP addresses as well, but you're saying it works in telnet so that might not be the problem.  You can run the container in --net=host mode to troubleshoot whether or not it's a Docker networking problem (that mode will skip dockerizing the networking for the container).